# Angular material 2 change root descendants checkbox color

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using angular material 2 tree with checkboxes and I want to dynamically change checkbox color. Easy way to do it is by clicking on it ((change) event is triggered ) and change `MatCheckboxChange.source.color`. Problem is, when I click on root node, is there any way how to get all descendant checkboxes sources (change colors of all descendants)? Example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rfwt1c)

template

```
<mat-checkbox class="checklist-leaf-node"
              [checked]="checklistSelection.isSelected(node)"
              (change)="todoLeafItemSelectionToggle(node, $event)">{{node.item}}</mat-checkbox>
```

code

```
todoLeafItemSelectionToggle(node: TodoItemFlatNode, event: MatCheckboxChange): void {
    event.source.color = 'warn'; // <---

    this.checklistSelection.toggle(node);
    this.checkAllParentsSelection(node);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a color variable to the template

```
<mat-checkbox class="checklist-leaf-node"
          [checked]="checklistSelection.isSelected(node)"
          [color]="color"
          (change)="todoLeafItemSelectionToggle(node, $event)">{{node.item}}</mat-checkbox>
```

then in your javascript

```
this.color = 'primary';
this.color = 'accent';
this.color = 'warn';
```

edit:

for dynamic colors `[color]="checklistSelection.isSelected(getParentNode(node)) ? 'primary' : 'warn'"`

Comment: this is not dynamic change ... i want to change all descendant checboxes color when parrent is checked.

Comment: `[color]="checklistSelection.isSelected(getParentNode(node)) ? 'primary' : 'warn'"`
. Would that work? Or something like that (I haven't tested)?